# Website Ads are opening external links when they load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, ads

I'm using ads from Adtech and Pubmatic on my site, but some of them are trying to open external protocols on mobile devices when they load.

So far I tried without success:

- Get a solution from the ad providers.
- Toggle the `sandbox` attribute of the iframe that is loading the app in order to restrict popups when the iframe loads.
- Override the `window.open` function.
- Look into the adblock source for ideas.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Is there any possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curious what the response from the ad providers was. And if that's not against the ToS, why use them?

Comment: They said that they are going to look into it, but has been weeks without further answers...